# how to calculate how much people are in last bus

Tags: python

I need to calculate how many people are in last bus.
I didnt get work.

I know i calculated first one also wrong. It must be "//" but it didnt work then used "round()" and it worked for me.

So if I choose:

number of people 259 and number of seats 40 then answer must be

- Number of bus needed 7 and In last bus number of seats 19

But I get:

- Number of bus needed 6 and In last bus number of seats 19

My code:

```
peop = int(input("Number of people: "))
bus  = int(input("Number of bus seats: "))

div  = round(peop / bus)

if (div <= 0) :
    print("Number of bus needed: " + str(1))
else:
    print("Number of bus needed: " + str(div))
cal = round(peop % bus)
if (cal == 0):
    print("In last bus number of people: " + str(bus))
else:
    print("In last bus number of people: " + str(cal))
```

Comment: Where do `inim` and `koht` come from and what do they mean?

Comment: What are `inim` and `koht`? They are undefined in your question.

Comment: edited code....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 things to be noted!

1) you need to ceil and not round!

```
import math
math.ceil(peop/bus)
```

2) it can be (and should be the below in python2)

```
div = peop/float(bus)
```

to get the right remainder

That is in python2,

```
>>> peop/bus
6
>>> peop/float(bus)
6.475
>>> round(peop/float(bus))
6.0
>>> math.ceil(peop/float(bus))
7.0
```

and in python3,

```
>>> peop/bus
6.475
>>> import math
>>> from math import ceil
>>> ceil(peop/bus)
7
```

Comment: Yes, But question is how to calculate how many people are in last bus.

Comment: its `peop%bus` and OP got it right already. The problem was in finding the correct number os buses!

Answer (score 0):

`round()` gives you integer closest to your float value. 259 / 40 is 6.475, the closest integer is 6.
What you need is next integer higher than your float. You can use `math.ceil(x)` for this:

```
import math
div = math.ceil(peop / bus)
```